# d3heatmap package error

Tags: r, heatmap

When I put in a matrix M that has dimensions of 634 by 2022, d3heatmap(M) spits out an error that says:

> all(vapply(s, is.integer, NA)) is not TRUE

I debugged it and it led to this line:

> debug: colClust <- as.hclust(hm$Colv)

Why is this?  The matrix I pass in is all numeric.

Comment: This code has been rewritten, but it seems that the clustering logic can't handle a matrix that big--now I get a "node stack overflow"` error. The same thing happens for both stats::heatmap and gplots::heatmap.2.